# Getting data from particular number of rows

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

Please have a look at the following code

```
public List getWordList(int listNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<String> list_a = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int counter = 0;

        try
        {
            String selectQuery = "select * from WordList";

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String englishWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("EnglishWord"));
                    String portugueseWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PortugueseWord"));
                    String englishHint = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("EnglishHint"));
                    String portuguestHint = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PortugueseHint"));

                    list_a.add(englishWord);
                    list_a.add(portugueseWord);
                    list_a.add(englishHint);
                    list_a.add(portuguestHint);
                }
                while(cursor.moveToNext());

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Data Retrieved: "+branches.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            cursor.close();
            return list_a;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Here, I am getting the data from the first row to last row. But, this is not what I need. If the 'number', the parameter is 1, I need data from row 0-9, if the 'number' is 2, I need data from row 10-19 if the 'number' is 3, I need data from row 20-29 like wise.

I am not familiar with SQLite, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging like functionality works best with the `SQL Limit Clause`. See Sqlite documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

Old query:

```
String selectQuery = "select * from WordList";
```

New query:

```
String selectQuery = "select * from WordList LIMIT 0,10";
```

The first digit indicates the offset. Offset can be corrected by using something like

```
int offset = (somePageValue-1)*10;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. You mean '0,9' instead of '0,10' ?

Comment: Nope 0 means offset 0 and then 10 elements which results in 0-9